# pip django-lfs gives error

Tags: python-2.7, pip, django-lfs

I'm trying to install Django-lfs on my pc(ubuntu 14.04 LTS).
I tried

```
sudo pip wheel django-lfs
```

but it gave me following error:

> Collecting django-paypal==0.1.2.lfs-2 (from django-lfs)
>       Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-paypal==0.1.2.lfs-2 (from django-lfs) (from versions: 0.1, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.5, 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5)
>       Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external django-paypal to allow).
>     No matching distribution found for django-paypal==0.1.2.lfs-2 (from django-lfs)

then I used the stronger command

```
sudo pip wheel --allow-all-external django-lfs
```

to resolve the issue, but again pip gave me the error below:

> Collecting django-paypal==0.1.2.lfs-2 (from django-lfs)
>       Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-paypal==0.1.2.lfs-2 (from django-lfs) (from versions: 0.1, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.5, 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5)
>       Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified django-paypal to allow).
>     No matching distribution found for django-paypal==0.1.2.lfs-2 (from django-lfs)

then i used this command :

```
sudo pip wheel --allow-all-external --allow-unverified django-paypal django-lfs
```

but It didn't change anything and again I got that last error, I thought maybe the pip's command chaining order causes the problem so entered command below :

```
sudo pip wheel --allow-unverified django-paypal --allow-all-external django-lfs
```

again it did't change anything, the error I got on this command was the same as two previous commands.

my pip version is 1.7.2, and I'm using python 2.7.6

It appears there is an issue with wheel command of pip, I wanna make sure that I didn't do anything wrong.
 
I manually downloaded the required django-paypal and installed it from its .whl file and then entered the command below and successfully(I have some issue binary dependencies of pillow but that is completely another story) installed the django-lfs

```
sudo pip install django-lfs
```

but I wanna know is it something to mention to pip developers , or i just made mistakes that prevented successful wheeling of django-lfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm faced the same error,but there is another method which worked for me.

Clone it from github using `git clone https://github.com/diefenbach/django-lfs.git`

then `python setup.py install`..
done.
Best of luck. ;)